# How safe is it to change variables using this[varName] = something in a function that has varName as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The function is not finished yet but I was wondering how "safe" it is to have a function that changes variables this way.

I'm using an angular service that has utility functions, `context` is `this` from the component that I call the function the rest should be self-explanatory.

```
changeValueOverTime(context: any, varToChange: string, amount: number, intevalTime: number) {
    const inteval = setInterval(() => {
      context[varToChange] = 200;
    }, intevalTime);
  }
```

Edit:

the completed function can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56513910/11202842

Comment: nothing wrong with that at all (other than the obscure side effect thing). What would be the alternative?

Comment: creating a function in the component that changes this.anyVariable directly, in the function i change the variable like context[varName] = something, my worry would be that if you call the function you can change any variable in context, was wondering if its not good practice to change variables using a function like this.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant by _other than the obscure side effect thing_. **Obscure** = not easily seen/found, and **side-effect** = changing something external to this function. Being either of these adjectives is not seen as a good practice. Being described as both is probably really, really not a seen as a good practice? BUT, it depends on your need to do this. If the exectution and use of this service is very well documented within those components that use this service, then it is probably OK to do this as a one-off (not-the-norm) thing.

Comment: It's really a bad idea! Use RXJS interval and map to emit new value each times and just subscribe this Observable into your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a bad idea! Use RXJS interval and map to emit new value each times and just subscribe this Observable into your component.

```
changeValueOverTime(intevalTime: number) {
    return interval(intevalTime).pipe(map(() => 200));
}
```

and in your component :

```
changeValueOverTime().subscribe(newValue => this.varToChange = newValue);
```