# animate a value over a specific time period

Tags: javascript

I thought creating a function that animates a value from `a` to `b` in `x` second was not  that difficult but i guess i was wrong or maybe im just tired, anyways how can i do that in javascript.

The function should look similar to this:

```
const varToChange = 0;
const amount = 100;
const time = 2; // time is in seconds but milisecons are also ok, doesn't really matter.
// feel free to add more parameters if necessary.
changeValueOverTime(amount, time) {
  // magic
}
```

expected outcome `varToChange` should be `100` after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `setInterval` of `setTimeout` javascript methods.

```js
let varToChange = 0;
const amount = 100;
const time = 2;
    
function changeValueOverTime(amount, time) {
  setTimeout(function(){
  varToChange++;
  console.log("varToChange : "+varToChange);
  varToChange !== amount ? changeValueOverTime(amount,time) : console.log("done");
  },(time*1000)/amount)
}

changeValueOverTime(amount,time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `varToChange` shouldn't be declared with `const` if you expect to mutate it. Secondly, use `setTimeout`.

```js
let varToChange = 0;
const amount = 100;
const time = 2;
function changeValueOverTime(amount, time) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    varToChange = amount;
  }, time * 1000);
}
changeValueOverTime(amount, time);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(varToChange);
}, 3000);
```

<sub>The second `setTimeout` is there so you can see the updated value of `varToChange`</sub>

Answer (score -1):

here is the function that i made in [playcode](https://playcode.io/336959?tabs=script.ts,preview,console), maybe i should have clarified that the function should be accurate, this function always returns the exact amount after the given time.

```
/**
* @example
* const sub = changeValueOverTime(2, 500, -10320, 1000).subscribe(retrunValues => {
*    valueToChange = changeValueOverTimeHelper(sub, retrunValues);
* });
* @param intevalTime Rate of Change in Milliseconds
* @param time Time to finish in Milliseconds
* @param amount amount that gets added or subtracted from the `initialValue`
* @param initialVaule Initial Value.
*/
function changeValueOverTime(intevalTime: number, time: number, amount: number, initialVaule: number): Observable < [number, boolean, number] > {
  const change = (amount / time) * intevalTime;
  const initialDate = new Date();
  return rxjs.interval(intevalTime).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.map(() => [
      initialVaule + (change * (new Date().getTime() - initialDate.getTime())) / intevalTime,
      new Date().getTime() - initialDate.getTime() >= time ? true : false,
      initialVaule + (change * time) / intevalTime
    ])
  );
}
/**
* @example
* const sub = changeValueOverTime(2, 500, -10320, 1000).subscribe(retrunValues => {
*    valueToChange = changeValueOverTimeHelper(sub, retrunValues);
* });
* @param subscipton Subscription to unsubscribe from when ``returnValues[1]`` is `true`
*/
function changeValueOverTimeHelper(subscipton: Subscription, returnValues: [number, boolean, number]): number {
  if (returnValues[1] === true) {
    subscipton.unsubscribe();
    return returnValues[2];
  } else {
    return returnValues[0];
  }
}

const sub = this.changeValueOverTime(5, 1000, 100, 0).subscribe(retrunValues => {
  console.log(changeValueOverTimeHelper(sub, retrunValues));
});
```